# Dymically open div in php?

Tags: php, html, css

Please be generous and kindfull in this.

I have a `php` project in which i have to show messages from `db`. I have done this but to show `receiver` names (somewhat like `gmail`) i am facing the problem.

Sample code of my work is like

```
<style>
#column_1,#column_2 {
    width:1200px;
    margin: 0 auto

}
    #fbCheck {
        display:none;
    }


    #fbCheck:not(:checked) ~ .sidebar-follow-button
    {
        display:none;
    }



    #fbCheck:checked ~ .sidebar-follow-button
    {
        display:block;
        z-index : 10;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: white;
        border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    padding: 5px;
    }
</style>
<?php 
$userList = array('megha','meena','karishma','aadhya','ananya','pooja','mahesh','megha','meena','karishma','aadhya','ananya','pooja','mahesh','megha','meena','karishma','aadhya','ananya','pooja','mahesh','megha','meena','karishma','aadhya','ananya','pooja','mahesh','megha','meena','karishma','aadhya','ananya','pooja','mahesh');
//$sendername = getSenderName($sender_id);
$sendername = 'Admin';

?>
<div id='column_1'>
<div class="header">Sender : <?php echo $sendername;?></div>
<div class="content">
<?php if(count($userList)<2){
    echo '<b>Receiver: </b>'.$userList[0].','.$userList[1];

}else{

    echo '<b>Receiver: </b>'.$userList[0].','.$userList[1].'...';
?>
     <input type="checkbox" id="fbCheck" />
        <label for="fbCheck">
          &#9660;
         </label>
         <div class="sidebar-follow-button" style="left: 91px;">
         <ul style="width :200px; height:80px; overflow:auto">
         <?php
         foreach($userList as $name){
         echo '<li align="center">'.$name.'</li>';
         }
         ?>
         </ul>   


    </div>
    <?php } ?>

    </div>

    <br>Your message starts from heree Your message starts from heree Your message starts from heree Your message starts from heree Your message starts from heree Your message starts from heree Your message starts from heree Your message starts from heree Your message starts from heree Your message starts from heree Your message starts from heree Your message starts from heree Your message starts from heree Your message starts from heree Your message starts from heree Your message starts from heree Your message starts from heree 
    Your message starts from heree Your message starts from heree Your message starts from heree Your message starts from heree     
    </div><br><br>

    <?php $userList = array('Bharat','Himanshu','Junaid','Bhavin','Anil');?>
    <div id='column_2'>
<div class="header">Sender : <?php echo $sendername;?></div>
<div class="content">
<?php if(count($userList)<2){
    echo '<b>Receiver: </b>'.$userList[0].','.$userList[1];

}else{

    echo '<b>Receiver: </b>'.$userList[0].','.$userList[1].'...';
?>
     <input type="checkbox" id="fbCheck" />
        <label for="fbCheck">
          &#9660;
         </label>
         <div class="sidebar-follow-button" style="left: 91px;">
         <ul style="width :200px; height:80px; overflow:auto">
         <?php
         foreach($userList as $name){
         echo '<li align="center">'.$name.'</li>';
         }
         ?>
         </ul>   


    </div>
    <?php } ?>

    </div>

    <br>Your message starts from heree Your message starts from heree Your message starts from heree Your message starts from heree Your message starts from heree Your message starts from heree Your message starts from heree Your message starts from heree Your message starts from heree Your message starts from heree Your message starts from heree Your message starts from heree Your message starts from heree Your message starts from heree Your message starts from heree Your message starts from heree Your message starts from heree 
    Your message starts from heree Your message starts from heree Your message starts from heree Your message starts from heree     
    </div>
```

I have show to `div's` here but this all is generated by php `foreach` loop and there may be many `content_1` `div`.

It works fine but when i click on second arrow to show sender list it shows me the first message receiver list all the time

[image]

This `div` opens every time even i click second arrow or any if there are more then 2

Please let me know how can i solve this issue

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you Using Ajax?

Comment: no php and css only

Comment: I am generating this code by looping in db row

Comment: Great.... but when you click on a Username you want to dynamically load the associated Data right? If that is the case, then AJAX may come in handy.... Because what you are trying to do is to react to  `CLICK` Event... which is a Client-Side Event.... but since it requires Loading Data from the Server, You still need PHP which is where AJAX comes in....

Comment: You are using php, css only or click and open the box is javascript event?

Comment: @daremachine till now i am using only php and css

Comment: @Poiz thanks i will try it with ajax :)

Comment: Css have no identification depend on block then you can not handle and specify what you want to show or hide. Simple solution is use what you have (render all content via php) and javascript for handling current click on current block for certain menu. Simple show/hide event like jquery.

Comment: @daremachine ok I will try it by jquery/ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
foreach($record as $data){
    if($condition){
         $body .=  "<div class="open">".$data."</div>";
    }else{
         $body .= "<div class="closed">".$data."</div>";
    }
}
echo $body;
```

Then create two CSS styles:

```
 .open{
      display: block;
 }
 .closed{
      display: none;
 }
```

The other comments are correct though.  If you are attempting to change you php output dynamically you need to rely on a ajax call.  Ajax will call your php file and return data that you can display to the user without refreshing the screen.

Comment: How can you account for the click event? Does CSS add behaviours or react to Events? And what happens with all the other Usernames in his list? Giving you an up-vote for your Efforts but not for providing a practical, workable solution....